# WinAPI: Displaying an image on a button - common way doesn't work

Tags: c++, image, winapi, button, bitmap

This causes me a headache: **I can't use a given bitmap to be shown on a button - Windows says it's an "Invalid parameter"**.

Here's my code:

```
// creating the button
const HWND hButton=::CreateWindow("button","text",WS_CHILD|VS_VISIBLE,0,0,100,100,hParent,0,editor.m_hInstance,NULL);
// loading the bitmap to be shown on a button
const HBITMAP hBmp=(HBITMAP)::LoadImage(editor.m_hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_MYBITMAP),IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADTRANSPARENT);
// associating the bitmap with a button that lacks the BS_BITMAP style (I want both image and text to be shown)
::SendMessage( hButton, BM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBmp );
// getting the error
const int err=::GetLastError(); // returns 0x56, "Invalid parameter"
```

Note that I *can* display the loaded image on the form's canvas, so the image is really correctly loaded.

I tried various resolutions of the bitmap (4 bits per pixel, 8 bits per pixel, standard pallete, true colour, 32 bits per pixel) - nothing worked. I read through tons of previous questions on this topic, all of which claim that the `::LoadImage` / `BM_SETIMAGE` combination is the ultimate solution - no result so far.

So my two questions:

1) Are there any requirements that an image has to fulfil to be shown on a button?

2) If not, then what am I actually doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance for a reply.

Tomas

Comment: Well, for starters, `GetLastError` is not relevant here: most windows API functions that actually pass error codes via `SetLastError` are documented as doing so - typically functions available from 'kernel32.lib'.

Comment: Yes, I'd love to have more information on what fails when `BM_SETIMAGE` is carried out, but `GetLastError` is the best that I can think of in this situation.

Comment: The `SendMessage` call has a return value. When sending a [BM_SETIMAGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761822.aspx) message, it returns the handle to the previously set image. You will have to take a look at the return value. Besides, you need to set certain [button styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951.aspx) for an image to show up, but your question doesn't show the code (or resource script) that creates the button. Don't make us guess, provide a [mcve] instead.

Comment: `GetLastError()` is only meaningful here if the `SendMessage` call itself fails.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: But `SendMessage` either cannot fail, or cannot report failure when sending `BM_SETIMAGE`. So in this case, you can always call `GetLastError`, but it's return value is only meaningful, if it's equal to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (which only happens when you're crossing integrity levels, i.e. not here).

Comment: The button has the `WM_CHILD` and `WM_VISIBLE` styles only. It doesn't have the `BS_BITMAP` set (for both text and image to be shown).

Comment: @IInspectable: It can also fail if e.g. you give it an invalid window handle (and `GetLastError` will return `ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE`).

Comment: To all: Have updated the question to account for IInspectable's comment on completeness - thank you.

Comment: Are you testing this on Windows XP?

Comment: Hi, yes, I'm testing it on Windows XP. I hope it makes no difference from Windows 7 and above :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
const int err=::GetLastError(); // returns 0x56, "Invalid parameter"
```

First, error `0x56` is a network error. See [System error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx)

> `ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD`
>       `86` (`0x56`)
>       The specified network password is not correct.

This can't be right. You are probably getting error `0x57` (`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`)

Second, this is how to do error check:

```
HBITMAP hBmp = (HBITMAP)::LoadImage(editor.m_hInstance, 
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADTRANSPARENT);
DWORD error;
if(!hBmp)
{
    error = GetLastError();
    //report error
}

SetLastError(0);
SendMessage(hButton, BM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBmp);
error = GetLastError();
//report the result, it may not be an error
```

`GetLastError` must appear immediately after the function which had failed. If you put `GetLastError` at a random place then the error message is meaningless.

Probably the problem is that you have not enabled Visual Styles in your application. Make sure you add visual styles to your manifest file.

If using Visual Studio you can just add this line to one of your *.cpp or *.h files:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' 
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' 
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Comment: `SendMessage` will not (and indeed cannot) report errors for [BM_SETIMAGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761822.aspx). A return value of `NULL` indicates, that previously the button didn't have a bitmap associated. This does not imply a failed call to `SendMessage`. I believe this is a case, where you will always call `GetLastError`, and test for known/interesting error codes.

Comment: @IInspectable You are right, I edited the answer. Error `0x57` will appear immediately after `SendMessage` if Visual Style is not set, but apparently `SendMessage` will give no indication if it failed or didn't fail.

Comment: `SendMessage` with `BM_SETIMAGE` cannot report errors, because all return values are valid. While other APIs returning an `HBITMAP` (like [CreateBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183485.aspx)) signal errors by returning `NULL`, that value is a potential success code when sending the `BM_SETIMAGE` message.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you - the error code is really 87, not 86, thank you Barmak Shemirani. But I'm affraid, I already use Common Controls version 6 exactly the way you suggested and it still doesn't work. And I've also checked the error _before_ calling `SendMessage` - it's zero, so it's the `BM_SETIMAGE` that causes the error. There will be something terribly stupid there. I will yet experiment with it for a while and if I don't come to a solution, I will turn myself to an owner drawn button as the ultimate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Write this code(delete declaration of hButton and write my code):

In main.cpp:

```
HWND hButton = CreateWindow("bttn", NULL, 
WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, | 
BS_BITMAP,100,100,100,100,hwnd,
```

(HMENU)44,NULL,NULL);

```
HBITMAP hBmp = LoadBitmap(g_hInstance, MYBMP);
```

In bmp.h

```
#define TEMP 21
#define MYBMP MAKEINTRESOURCE(TEMP)
```

In set.rc

```
#define TEMP 21
TEMP BITMAP"bitmap.bmp"
```